# Vuex: State member is undefined by default

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have this in `store.js`

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';
import actions from './actions';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: { 
        folders: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')),
        folder: {name:'', todos:[]}
    },
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions
});
```

and I have this in `getters.js`

```js
export default {

    //some functions ,
    todos(state){
        console.log(state.folder)
        return state.folder.todos;
    },
    //some other functions
```

and In the console I have this

```
{__ob__: Observer}
folder: undefined,
folders: Array(1),
pair and values...
```

[image: Console]

what I do not understand is why `folder` is undefined? while folders is defined!!
Please someone expalin why this is happening!!
By the way, I get an error when I call `getters.todos`.

Comment: Exactly what error do you get from trying to call `getters.todos`?

Comment: @Phil cannot read 'todos' of undefined 'folder'

Comment: See the little _i_ next to the object in your console screenshot? That means the object was modified after being shown in the console. I would hazard a guess that something else in your code is setting `folder` to `undefined`

Comment: yup. that makes sense. I figured out the problem, I used a mutation method to reset `folder` value. thnx.